# Why can a function not have a Static parameter?

Tags: c

The following is the code in c.

```
     fact(2);
     void fact(static int i)
     {..}
```

Output:Error cannot have static arguments
  So why can't we have static arguments in a function?

Comment: Because the C *language* does not allow for such ..

Comment: What would it mean?

Comment: Can u please explain me the reason behind this...and can we do it in java...

Comment: @ghostrider Java is not C. In Java, the static keyword means a class method, in C it's something completely different.

Comment: @H2CO3 in java static variables means there is only one copy of that variable for each object made..so does this mean similar to static in c?

Comment: @H2CO3 sir you said that static variables are invisible to outside world.which is not met by arguments.but the values of arguments are destroyed after the function is over..so how can it be visible to outside world?

Comment: @ghostrider becusse you can give'em a value by calling the function with arguments.

Comment: Sir please correct me if i am wrong..so because we cannot assign them values by passing parameters to static arguments..because they are not available outside world..

Comment: @ghostrider : If a function supports static arguments, imagine how would a recursion possibly work?

Comment: When I was trying to learn about "static array indices" in C, my Google search led to this question. Since it's been closed and deemed "not a real question" anyway, let me cross-link to this post for others who stumble upon this answer in search of "static array indices in parameter declarations" in C: https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The static keyword means that a variable may have only and exactly one instance in its scope, and that instance is invisible out of its scope. Neither of these requirements make sense for a function argument: it may be called multiple times, at a different memory address, and as it's meant for communication, it has to be visible to the outer world.

Comment: To make all the fools happy, it could cause the argument to be copied into an object of static storage duration when the function is invoked, just to make the function gratuitously non-thread-safe... ;-)

Comment: @R.. are you a politician? (just kidding)

Comment: @H2CO3 So is it possible in java?

Comment: @ghostrider IDK, I'm not a Java guy... But I suppose not. Feeding a class method to another function doesn't make sense out of the C and scripting family.

Comment: @ghostrider no, you can not have static parameters in Java.  It doesn't make any sense.  Why do you want a static parameter?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @dsh thanks from me too for the clarification.

Comment: @H2CO3 please correct me if i m wrong.So because we cannot assign values to static arguments since they are not visible to the parameters..we cannot have static arguments??

Comment: @ghostrider sorry but I don't really understand that.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am trying to say that since static variables are not visible to outside world.Therefore we cannot assign them values through parameters.or is there any other reason why we cannot include static arguements?

Comment: @ghostrider it again is ambigous that you wrote. You **can** do seomthing like `static int i = 0; some_function(i);`

Answer (score 8):

Trying to apply `static` to an argument doesn't make much sense, so the standard doesn't allow it (§6.7.5.3/2: "The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is `register`.")

Comment: Well, it *could* make sense, given an appropriate definition of `static` in that context .. (If it *was* part of the C language then there would have been a case that "made sense".)

Comment: @pst: while you *could* undoubtedly define it to mean something in that context, I'd say about the last thing C needs is yet *another* meaning attached to `static`.

Comment: I never suggested adding one. I was pointing out the argument seems invalid. (Along the lines of "because there is a watch there was a maker?" although that doesn't seem right either ..) There are many language constructs that might appear silly, yet they are there. I would argue it "doesn't make much sense" because "it's not" C .. and not the other-way around.

Comment: @pst: What meaning could you attach to it that would accomplish something useful for a parameter, and bear even a vague resemblance to the current meaning attached to `static` in C?