# Error: Storage class specifiers invalid for parameter declarations

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, declaration, gnu

when I compile my program for Linux I get this error:

```
error: storage class specifiers invalid for parameter declarations
```

This only happens on Linux as it compiles fine for Windows.
The line of code is:

```
int Start(static const char* m_vertexshader, static const char* m_fragmentshader);
```

If you need any details or info just ask, using GNU C compiler (g++)

Comment: Thought it needed it but turns out it didn't. Thanks much!
Working now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. You may not use keyword static in parameter declarations and I do not know why you use it.

Comment: Thanks much, didn't know this, doesn't happen on VS 2010. :)

Comment: @Boncey MS VC++ has many so called "language extensions" that in fact are simply compiler bugs.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is surely more instructive to tell people why they cannot use something instead of "i do not know why you use it".

Comment: if you end up here check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811975/why-can-a-function-not-have-a-static-parameter for explanation.